# OCR Actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, ocr

Hi guys i want to create a OCR in Actionscript 3. At first i thought that i would create a neural network in AS3. But, it's very difficult.  Any guidelines on how to proceed would be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

I found this:  http://code.google.com/p/zeez/

If you go to the ZeezSample.fla you need to change the main stage class to ZeezSample.   It was set to a non-existent file thus the .fla was useless.   With that tweak you can see the algo at work.   I'm trying to find a way to trim this down and simply recognize a few basic numbers in a flash bitmap / bitmapdata pulled from a webcam.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Alchemy](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/alchemy/) and find a C/C++ library which you would then wrapp for AS3.

Comment: Oh i tried that...had lot of problems with bytearray manipulation

Comment: ok, so, give us some more info. What is your use case? etc...But basically, I don't know of any OCR library implemented in AS3, and doubt you might find one. Basically, I would delegate the task to any existing OCR library that you can interact through a CLI. Then, if your project is Air you can wrapp it with the app on install and use the new native features. If is an online app, then i.e. have PHP exec a call  to it.

Answer (score 0):

I found this one, but I never tried it: http://code.google.com/p/as3ocr/