# AS3 - Extract text from image

Tags: actionscript-3, text, text-extraction

Is it possible to extract the text from an image like this?[image]

(I'd like to display it in an textfield afterwards)
Thanks. 
Uli

Comment: [Yes, it is.](https://www.google.hu/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8&ion=1#hl=hu&sclient=psy-ab&q=ocr%20actionscript&oq=&gs_l=&pbx=1&fp=8b876a2d54e172d1&ion=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&biw=1422&bih=712)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is Optical Character Recognition.  Here is a similar question:

[OCR Actionscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299258/ocr-actionscript)

Though sadly it has no clear-cut answer.   There is no native class/framework for doing it in AS3, though I'm sure it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

This is a task where you'd employ web service. I know Google Docs can OCR an image for you. ABBYY, whose FineReader is one of the best in the business, also provides an OCR web service. Google has open-sourced their OCR software. You can conceivable set it up on your own server.